# how to stream from iphone to a wireless laptop over same network

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming, iphone

I have an iPhone app (Streamer Lite).  It streams iPhone video over wireless to a wired PC (Foxfire and Chrome) on the same wireless network easily.  I can't get it to work to my laptop with another wireless connection on the same network.  There are no adjustments to make or setup, other than the local address of the streaming device (192.168.1.5:80).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Port 80 is normally HTTP. Does the app tell you to use port 80?

Comment: Yes. The app defaults to Port 80.  It does work when streaming to a wired computer.  I don't really see a difference as to why it prefers a wired IP vs a wireless IP on the same network.  Thoughts?

Comment: Also, I should mention I have the Norton firewall, but it is turned off.

Comment: I can't think of what might be causing this. Port forwarding wouldn't be an issue because you're on the same wireless network. Do you have another wireless device you could test?

Comment: @numbermaniac :  I tried it on a couple different networks/phones with the same result.  The app is called Streamer (iPhone).

Comment: @numbermaniac - thank you for your thinking about the issue.  I rebooted all the computers and the routers.  Two of the three routers now work with the app.  Not quite sure why the last one doesn't, but i now know the app works as promised.

Comment: Great! Good to know it's (almost) working now :)